# Add a time interval between playing a wav file without locking up the GUI

Tags: c#, silverlight, timer

I'm totally stumped on this one. I am creating a "click track" for an app that I'm making in Silverlight using C# (no VB.NET please). I have a slider on the page that I would like to represent the time interval between clicks. That being said, I would like my code to look something like this:

```
int i = 0;

while(i < 1)
{
    using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("click.wav"))
    {
        var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
    }       
    ClickInterval(clickSlider.Value);
    i++;    
}
```

ClickInterval() represents the method for the time interval between clicks. I'm not sure how to create this interval. A timer simply locks up the GUI and I'm not sure if threading is the way to go since this could create too many threads (which I'm not really sure that it would be a problem). Perhaps even the above code could be rewritten. Any ideas on this one folks? Any suggestions would be a big help!

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I was able to resolve the issue:

Comment: private void TestMetronome(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer myDispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        myDispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000); // 1000 Milliseconds (1 second) 
        myDispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(Each_Tick);
        myDispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

Comment: public void Each_Tick(object o, EventArgs sender)
    {
        using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("click.wav"))
        {
            var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            effect.Play();
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Any `Sleep` in the same thread as the GUI will lock it up.  You need to use another thread or a `BackgroundWorker` to play the clicks.

Your thread will contain code similar to above:

```
var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("click.wav")
var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);

while(true)
{
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    effect.Play();     
    ClickInterval(clickSlider.Value);    
}
```

As you can see, this will run continuously in the background until you stop the Thread.  (If you have a 'stop clicking' button on the GUI, you can set a variable that will break out of the while loop.)  I also brought out `stream` and `effect` so the thread wont keep creating and destroying them.

`ClickInterval` should basically call `Thread.Sleep(clickSlider.Value)` if the value being passed is in milliseconds.

Comment: Thread.Sleep locks the window - that was my first idea too.  And OP specifically said, not to lock the GUI.

Comment: @Chuck: Not if you do it on a thread *other* than the GUI thread. This is why you never do work like this on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 0):

My Original idea wouldn't work, but this might:

```
int i = 0;
string[] songs = new string[] { "click.wav" };
Timer timer = new Timer(){ Interval = clickSlider.Value * 1000 }; // 1000 = 1 second
EventHandler handler = (s,e) => 
{ 
    timer.Stop(); 
    PlayNext(songs, i++); 
    if(i < songs.Length)
        timer.Start(); 
};
timer.Tick += handler;

handler(null,null); // starts timer and plays first song.
```

...

```
void PlayNext(string[] songs, int index)
{
    using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream(songs[index]))
    {
        var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
        FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        effect.Play();
    }    
}
```